# Combined string isn't working for libCurl in C++

Tags: c++, libcurl

Basically, my program/code I'm using now is returning a message from a PHP script. The issue I'm having is when I give it a combined string for the URL, it doesn't return anything. But when I enter it manually, it returns the correct information. Here is the code I am using below:

```cpp
std::string Login(std::string uname, std::string pass)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;
    std::string path = "localhost/files/login.php?username=" + uname + "&password=" + pass;
    std::cout << uname << "  " << pass;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost/files/login.php?username=123&password=123");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        return readBuffer;
    }
    return "Failed";

}
```

This way works because I enter the URL manually, but when I do this it doesn't return anything:

```cpp
std::string path = "localhost/files/login.php?username=" + uname + "&password=" + pass;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, path);
```

I'm uncertain whether I'm using the wrong variable or something else. I'm new to using PHP and libCurl and anything web related.

Answer (score 1):

[`CURLOPT_URL`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html) expects a C-style null-terminated `char*` string pointer as input, not a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).  You can use the [`std::string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method to get a compatible `const char*` pointer from the `std::string`:

```cpp
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, path.c_str());
```